# Extract data from oracle db in .txt format

Tags: sql, oracle, export-to-csv

How to extract data from oracle db in .txt format  & i need to post this files to sap server.

please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spool` in sql/plus like below which will write to `result.txt`

```
spool result.txt    
select col1, col2, ... , coln from your_table;    
spool off
```

See [Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9518534700346581975) for more information